# CString and cout printing on two lines

Tags: cout, cstring

I am writing a program and i have two c strings `first Name[21];` and `last Name[21];`
i want to output to the console e.g. `cout << first Name << " " << last Name;`, but when i do it prints first Name on one line then last Name on another line. I don't know what to do to make them print on one line any help?

Comment: Probably, `first_Name` actually contains a newline in the string. Show the code you used to fill in `Name`.  Also, it is not called `first Name` because you cannot have spaces in identifiers in C++ (assuming this is a C++ question)